# Outlook 2013 keep asking for password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, group-policy, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

We having problem where outlook is keep asking for password every time you start outlook.

Things I tried

- I have created new outlook profile - still same problem
- Clear all passwords from password manager - still same problem
- Deleted the .OST file - still same problem.
- Always prompt for logon credentials - this is not tick
- I have tried this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290684

Only happening on Office 2013 not office 2007

One thing I did notices when I was debugging the problem.
When I removed the office and reinstalled the problem went away for whole 1 week but then on Monday it start asking for password again which makes be thing that they is something in group policy which is causing this.

We are using

- Windows 7
- Office 365 (2013)
- Our emails are being hosted by Microsoft clod

I don't know what else to try or check.

Comment: Please mirror the answer I wrote out, works for Outlook 2013 too. See here: http://superuser.com/questions/759635/cannot-connect-office-365-email-with-outlook-2010/784421#784421

Comment: @SamuelNicholson does that answer also hold true for windows 8.1 users?

Comment: @Thomas In my experience it is dependent on the Outlook version, I've used this fix on Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines, I assume 8.1 should be no different.